# R Shiny - How to remove flickering when using SliderInput to animate static images?

Tags: css, r, shiny, shinydashboard

I am building a shiny dashboard and plan to use SliderInput to animate a set of exisiting pngs. To do so, in the UI I have:

```
tabItem(tabName = 'Image',
            fluidRow(
              box(title = "", status="primary",solidHeader = F,width = 9,
                  uiOutput("animate_img"),
                  tags$style(type="text/css", "recalculating { opacity: 1.0 !important; }") # NOT WORKING
              ),
              box(
                title = "Options", status="info",solidHeader = TRUE,width = 3,
                sliderInput("dates_img",
                            "Dates:",
                            min = as.Date("2017-01-01","%Y-%m-%d"),
                            max = as.Date("2018-12-31","%Y-%m-%d"),
                            value=as.Date("2017-01-01"),
                            timeFormat="%Y-%m-%d",
                            animate=animationOptions(interval=1000, loop = TRUE))
              )
            )
    )
```

and in the server I have:

```
  output$animate_img <- renderUI({
    y <- year(input$dates_img)
    d <- yday(input$dates_img)
    filename <- sprintf("img_%d_%d.png",d,y)
    tags$img(src = filename, width="100%")
  })
```

While this code works to display the images, when I use the "play" button on the sliderInput to animate the images, there is flickering as each image loads. I would like to have a smooth animation if possible.

As suggested [here](https://groups.google.com/g/shiny-discuss/c/9faA5OUm2Hc), I have tried adding `tags$style(type="text/css", "recalculating { opacity: 1.0 !important; }")` to the UI, but this does not work.

Any recommendations for how to prevent the images from flickering as the animation plays? Thank you!

Comment: so part of shiny's framework is that it loads things if and only if they are "asked for" by the user in some way. So I don't strictly know if it's possible to load all the possible configurations up front while the server is loading itself before the user calls for them. That's partially just the nature of R shiny. I would love to be proven wrong about this, though.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get it to work without any flickering by simply adjusting how the CSS is included in the rendered HTML. I used `shinyjs::inlineCSS` in my example, but the same could be done via sourcing an external stylesheet `.css` file with `tags$head` and `tags$script` or via `includeCSS`, etc. The key is to have the CSS loaded into the full HTML document's head (can verify via browser DevTools):

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyjs)
library(lubridate)

ui <- fluidPage(
    shinyjs::inlineCSS(
        "recalculating { opacity: 1.0 !important; }"
    ),
    fluidRow(
        box(title = "",
            status = "primary",
            solidHeader = F,
            width = 9,
            uiOutput("animate_img")
        ),
        box(
            title = "Options",
            status = "info",
            solidHeader = TRUE,
            width = 3,
            sliderInput("dates_img",
                        "Dates:",
                        min = as.Date("2017-01-01","%Y-%m-%d"),
                        max = as.Date("2018-12-31","%Y-%m-%d"),
                        value = as.Date("2017-01-01"),
                        timeFormat = "%Y-%m-%d",
                        animate = animationOptions(interval = 1000, loop = TRUE))
        )
    )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$animate_img <- renderUI({
    y <- year(input$dates_img)
    d <- yday(input$dates_img)
    filename <- sprintf("img_%d_%d.png",d,y)
    tags$img(src = filename, width="100%")
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Just make sure that your image files are placed directly in the `www` folder and it should work.

Thanks,
Jimmy